# ubiquityIdentityToken vs. CKContainer accountStatusWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

Which method is better to decide which user is logged in?

```
let ubiquityIdentityToken = NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken
```

returns a token, and client can compare wether it is the same than last time. The advantage that it returns token if device is offline too.

`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` returns only a status value, but not an ID or token about who is logged in. So in offline mode it is useless.

Am I right?

My other problem, that sometimes even user is logged in and online `ubiquityIdentityToken` returns nil.

How do you retrieve user ID at launch?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using CloudKit then the CKContainer [`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:) method is how you should check whether the user is logged into iCloud or not (supported since iOS 8.0). The [CloudKit Quick Start shows an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW8) of how to use it.

[`fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:) is how you should get the user's record ID, which is scoped to that CloudKit container but the same for that iCloud account across devices.

In iOS 9.0, you'll also have [`CKAccountChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/CKAccountChangedNotification), which will notify your app when the iCloud status on the device changes.

Comment: I get a strange error, logged into iCloud, but `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` returns a `.NoAccount` value. I guess this method works only if private database is used, but I am using only public DB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091839/ckcontainer-accountstatuswithcompletionhandler-returns-wrong-value

Comment: @János I'm having the same problem now using the Simulator with the Development database. Looking for someone who figured what the problem was. It only happens in one code path - the short one - and not on the longer path.

Comment: @János I figured it out - the class that was asking for the account information was getting deallocated while the accountStatusWithCompletionHandler was in-process. For whatever reason that causes the problem (or it could be multiples of such requests, not really sure).