# CKContainer accountStatusWithCompletionHandler returns wrong value

Tags: ios, cloudkit

`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` method returns `.NoAccount` value. Any idea why returned value is not `.Available`? I am logged in to iCloud, and connecting to internet.

Doc says `.NoAccount` means:

> The user’s iCloud account is not available because no account
>   information has been provided for this device.

I do not receive any error. The reason may be that app is not using private database? Doc says:

> Call this method before accessing the private database to determine
>   whether that database is available.

Comment: accountStatusWithCompletionHandler this method should return error as well. Could you please print error also.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk You only get an error with the "could not determine" result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out, iCloud Drive was turned off for the app.

Comment: Had the same exact issue after switching to a new phone. Was about to ask you where you enabled iCloud Drive as I couldn't find it...found it, so for anyone with the same issue, go to settings->icloud. Make sure icloud drive is switched on, then scroll down to enable it for any apps requiring it. 
This must have changed recently as I never had to do this before and have been using CK for awhile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code sample show status with iCloud. Probably request permission or promo user to login  on `.NoAccount` case. I am thinking this is a case when you are not connected to the iCloude.

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler({status, error in
        switch status {
            case .Available, .Restricted:
            container.requestApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.PermissionUserDiscoverability,
                completionHandler: { applicationPermissionStatus, error in
                // handle applicationPermissionStatus for statuses like CKApplicationPermissionStatus.Granted, .Denied, .CouldNotComplete, .InitialState
            })
            case .CouldNotDetermine, .NoAccount:
                // Ask user to login to iCloud
        }
    })
```

Comment: I am connected to iCloud in Settings

Comment: @János I will retest this code again with my account